# HTML/Javascript Bookmarks technique?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarks

I don't know how to explain it correctly (and it may seem as a silly question) but looking at pages such as `http://www.billboard.com/#/charts/hot-100` you see there is a `#` "bookmark".

The same applies for Wikipedia's user preferences page `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-personal` where every section is accessed through the '#'.

How is this done? JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

`#` just jumps to the element on the page with the id following the `#`

For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#mp-tfp-h2

It is the browser doing that. Nothing to do with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, the # corresponds to a `A` tag's `id` attribute:

```
<a id="here"/>
```

You can put these anywhere on an html page, and you link to them like this:

```
<a href="thePage.html#here">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the part after the `#` and do whatever you want: load and display some data, for example.

Here's how it's done in javascript:

```
var theHashPart = window.location.hash;
```

Note that this variable will contain the hash sign ("#/charts/hot-100"), so you might want to strip it off.